# Laravel Eager loading select columns

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I get the following error when i try this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select()
Running this:

```
Portfolio::find($id)->transactions
        ->select('id','date','symbol','transaction_type','qty','amount');
```

but this works.

```
Portfolio::find($id)->transactions
```

I have a relationship in my portfolio model for

```
$this->hasMany('Transaction','portfolio_id');
```

So now to the real question. How can i select certain fields from the transactions table using eager loading? or do i need to do it using query builder

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
$portfolio = Portfolio::with(array('transactions' => function($q){
    $q->select(array('id','date','symbol','transaction_type','qty','amount'));
}))->whereId($id)->first();
```

This will return you `Portfolio` model along with related `transactions` and you may use following:

```
$portfolio->transactions->first()->amount
```

Also, you may loop them. But following will give you only related models:

```
Portfolio::find($id)->transactions()
         ->get(array('id','date','symbol','transaction_type','qty','amount'));
```

Check more on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) about `eager loading`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `get` instead of `select`. If you want to select only some specific fields from the database, then you can pass an array to the `get` method, like in the following example:

```
Portfolio::find($id)->transactions()
        ->get(array('id','date','symbol','transaction_type','qty','amount'));
```

Comment: so i tried that and got there error array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Comment: Use transactions() instead of transactions as I have changed in my answer. If you have done everything else correctly, then that should solve your problem.